# Monitor loses my desktop on F7 - how do I reconnect from F1 shell?

Tags: xfce, hdmi, 16.10

I don't exactly know why this happens, but when I run XFCE4 with a normal monitor, I lose the desktop if I unplug the HDMI cable.

When I plug it back in, the screen is blank. All the apps are still running though.

What I have been doing up til now is switching to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, logging in and killing the `xfce4-session`.

This then restarts the GUI.

Can I get the GUI back without killing it, so that my GUI apps like browsers and editors don't get closed down?